# Pythonic way to store top 10 results

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project that runs for a couple hours before it's finished all it's calculations. I would like to hold the top 10 results of the calculation as it progresses.

There's the obvious way of doing:

```
if calc > highest_calc:
    second_calc = highest_calc
    highest_calc = calc
if calc < highest_calc and calc > second_calc:
    third_calc =  second_calc
    second_calc = calc
if calc < second_calc and calc > third_calc:
    fourth_calc = third_calc
    third_calc = calc
etc.
```

But is there a better, more dynamic and pythonic way?

**Bonus**

For my project, each calcultion has three coresponding names with it: `name_a` `name_b` `name_c` . What I don't want is more then one of the top 10 values to have the same three names. But, if the last `calc` has the same names, I want to keep the highest of the two. What's the best way to do this?

For example, lets say `2.3` is the value of `calc`, using `MCD` `SBUX` and `CAT` to calculate `calc`. But what if I had already made a `calc` using `MCD` `SBUX` and `CAT` and it made it to the top to? How do I find the value of this `calc` so I can see if it is less than or greater then the new `calc`. If it is greater than, remove the old calc with the same and add the new `calc`. If it is less than, `pass` new calc. Hopefully that makes sense:

```
If name_a in top10 and name_b in top10 and name_c in top10:
   if calc > old_calc_with_same_names:
       add_calc = calc, name_a, name_b, name_c
       top10.insert(bisect.bisect(calc, top10[0]), add_calc)
else:
   add to top10
```

**Finished Code**

```
csc = []
top_ports = []
add_sharpe = [sharpe, name_a, weight_a, exchange_a, name_b, weight_b, exchange_b, name_c, weight_c, exchange_c]
    if init__calc == 0:
            csc.append(add_sharpe)
    if init__calc > 1:
        if name_a == prev_name_a and name_b == prev_name_b and name_c == prev_name_c:
            csc.append(add_sharpe)
        if name_a != prev_name_a or name_b != prev_name_b or name_c != prev_name_c:
            if csc:
                hs = max(csc, key=lambda x: x[0])
                if top_ports:
                    ls = min(top_ports, key=lambda x: x[0])
                    if hs[0] > ls[0]:
                        hsi = csc.index(hs)
                        top_ports.append(csc[hsi])
                else:
                    hsi = csc.index(hs)
                    top_ports.append(csc[hsi])
            csc = []
            csc.append(add_sharpe)
```

Later on in the script...

```
top_ports = sorted(top_ports, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
print "The highest sharpe is: {0}".format(top_ports[0])
print " ==============================================="
print " ==============================================="
print datetime.now() - startTime
print "Second: {0}".format(top_ports[1])
print "Third: {0}".format(top_ports[2])
print "Fourth: {0}".format(top_ports[3])
print "Fifth: {0}".format(top_ports[4])
```

etc.

Comment: If every result has exactly three names associated with it, can I simplify your bonus requirements to: get the top 10 results such that each result has a different combination of names, filling the remaining places with the highest remaining results regardless of their names when there are less than 10 unique name combinations? And just about how many names and calculations should I expect?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien See the updated question for the solution I am using currently. It seems to work good now, noted that it does seem somewhat slow. The script usually runs between 1,000,000 and 1,000,000,000 calculations. There will be between 40 and 150 unique names, but they are in combinations, which explains the large calculation number. The script performs about 1000 calcs. Let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: This code doesn't mean much to me given all the cryptic names/concepts (`csc`/`init__calc`). I can't go and figure out this code and make an exact solution for you. You'll just have to tell me what you're really after. Do you want a top 10 where preferably each name combination is unique, i.e. do you value the uniqueness of a name combination higher than the value of the result? Most confusing is the requirement re: "last" calculation. What is last really? The previous one with the same name combination, no matter when it happened, or only if it was actually the previous calculation overall?

Comment: The more often I read your requirements, the stronger my impression that you really want what I was proposing in my now first comment. Assuming we're doing top 3 instead of top 10, given `[1ABC, 3BCD, 5CDE]`, when `2BCD` comes we discard it because `2 > 1` but we already have `BCD` with `3 > 2` (so we're preferring the uniqueness of `BCD` over the fact that `2 > 1`). When `4BCD` comes, we use it to replace `3BCD`. Correct? And given `[1ABC, 3BCD]`, when `2BCD` comes, and there is place left, do we discard it too or use it for not having a candidate yet that does have a unique name combination?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Yes, that is correct! (Your last comment). Given `[1ABC, 3BCD]`, we do discard it, yes. There are going to be so many calcs and names later on that there is no worry of filling up a top 10 or top 3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `heapq` module. Instead of needlessly storing all results, at every step it adds the new result and then efficiently removes the lowest—which may be the one just added—effectively keeping the top 10. Storing all results is not necessarily bad though; it can be valuable to collect statistics, and make it easier to determine what to keep afterwards.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappushpop

heap = []
for x in [18, 85, 36, 57, 2, 45, 55, 1, 28, 73, 95, 38, 89, 15, 7, 61]:
    calculation_result = x + 1 # Dummy calculation
    if len(heap) < 10:
        heappush(heap, calculation_result)
    else:
        heappushpop(heap, calculation_result)

top10 = sorted(heap, reverse=True) # [96, 90, 86, 74, 62, 58, 56, 46, 39, 37]
```

Note that this module has more useful functions to only request the highest/lowest value, et cetera. This may help you to add the behavior concerning names.

Actually this construct is so common that it is available as `heapq.nlargest`. However, to not store all your results after all, you'd have to model the calculator as a generator, which is a bit more advanced.

```
from heapq import nlargest

def calculate_gen():
    for x in [18, 85, 36, 57, 2, 45, 55, 1, 28, 73, 95, 38, 89, 15, 7, 61]:
        yield x + 1 # Dummy calculation

top10 = nlargest(10, calculate_gen()) # [96, 90, 86, 74, 62, 58, 56, 46, 39, 37]
```

**Bonus**

Here is some idea to make the results unique for each combination of associated names.

Using a heap is not going to cut it anymore, because a heap is not good at locating any item that is not the absolute minimum/maximum, and what we are interested in here is some kind of local minimum given the criteria of a name combination.

Instead, you can use a `dict` to keep the highest value for each name combination. First you need to encode the name combination as an immutable value for it to work as a key, and because the order of the names shouldn't matter, decide on some order and stick with it. I'm going with alphabetical strings to keep it simple.

In the code below, each result is put in the `dict` at a place that is unique for its name combination—therefore normalization might be needed—as long as there isn't a better result already. Later the top *n* is compiled from the highest results for each combination.

```
from heapq import nlargest

calculations = [('ABC', 18), ('CDE', 85), ('BAC', 36), ('CDE', 57),
                ('ECD',  2), ('BAD', 45), ('EFG', 55), ('DCE',  1)]

highest_per_name_combi = dict()

for name_combi, value in calculations:
    normal_name_combi = ''.join(sorted(name_combi)) # Slow solution
    current = highest_per_name_combi.get(normal_name_combi, float('-inf'))
    highest_per_name_combi[normal_name_combi] = max(value, current)

top3 = nlargest(3, highest_per_name_combi.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The only problem with this approach might be the amount of memory used. Since with 150 names there can be 551300 (150 choose 3) combinations, you may have to decide to clean up the `dict` every now and then, which is simple. In the loop, check for the size of the `dict` and if it exceeds some (still large) number, compose the current top *n* and create a new, minimal `dict` from it. Also, some micro optimizations could be applied by reducing the number of lookups/calls, e.g. not using `get` and/or `max`.

All of this would be a lot easier if you'd have control over the order in which calculations are performed. If you'd know that the next 1000 calculations are all for the same name combination, you could just find the best of those first before adding it to the overall results.

Also, with a truly massive amount of results, the simplest way may actually be the best. Just write them to a file in a convenient format, sort them there (first by name combination, then reversely by value), take only the first occurrence for each name combination (easy when they are grouped) and sort the result again, just by value.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way to store all your scores in a list, then sort it in reverse (highest first) and take the first 10.

```
import random
# sample random scores
scores = [int(1000*random.random()) for x in xrange(100)]

# uncomment if scores must be unique
#scores = set(scores)
topten = sorted(scores, reverse=True)[:10]

print topten
```

If you need to prevent duplicate scores in the list use a set.

This is the 'vanilla' method for getting the top 10 scores, but it misses the opportunity for an optimization, that will make a difference for larger data sets.

Namely the entire list need not be sorted each time the top 10 are asked for, if the top ten score list is maintained as scores are added. For this perhaps 2 lists could be maintained; the complete list and the top 10, for the later the `heapq` method suggested by @thijs van Dien is superior.

Comment: How about just `topten = sorted(scores)[-10:]`?

Comment: This will become quite inefficient if the number of scores is high, because you are sorting the entire list. Theoretically only the first 10 elements have to be sorted, the others just have to be smaller than the first 10. Nevertheless for (relative) small numbers of scores this is probably the most simple and thus best solution.

Comment: I'd suggest using `random.sample(range(1000), 100)` instead. It doesn't mean exactly the same, because it has a better distribution and no repetitions/replacement, but it serves the purpose and reads nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a comment, here's my improved solution, using the idea of building a list of topten.  Using heapq as indicated by the other answer is obviously much better.  This solution will have worst-case run-time of N*10, and using heap will reduce that to N*log2(10).  That could be noticeable if one wants not top ten, but for example top ten thousand values.  But more importantly, using heapq has great readability, understandability, and correctness advantages.

```
data = [18, 85, 73, 36, 57, 2, 45, 55, 1, 28, 73, 95, 38, 89, 15, 7, 61]

# start off the topten list
# with a sentinel value to simplify the add loop.
sentinel = 12345   # the sentinel could be any value.
topten = [sentinel]

def add(newvalue):
    length = len(topten)

    # temporarily overwrite the sentinel with the new value
    topten[-1] = newvalue

    # find the right place in the topten for the new value
    # iterate over topten in reverse order, skipping the sentinel position
    for i in xrange(-2, -length-1, -1): # -2, -3, ..., -length
        if newvalue > topten[i]:
            topten[i+1] = topten[i]
            topten[i] = newvalue
        else:
            break

    # fix up the topten list.
    # if we haven't yet gathered all top ten, grow the list
    # else discard the last element of the list.
    if length < 11:
        topten.append(sentinel)
    else: # length >= 11 i.e. == 11
        topten[-1] = sentinel

for v in data: add(v)
print topten[:-1] # drop the sentinel
```

Adding uniqueness based on names... should be possible by maintaining a set.

For reference, my initial solution is below.  It has the problems of picking the initial value, and spurious entries if total number of calculations is less than 10.

```
data = [18, 85, 73, 36, 57, 2, 45, 55, 1, 28, 73, 95, 38, 89, 15, 7, 61]

import sys
floor = -sys.maxint - 1  # won't work in Python 3, as there is no sys.maxint
                         # for float, use float('-inf')
topten = [floor] * 10

def add(newvalue):
    # iterate over topten in reverse order
    for i in xrange(-1, -11, -1): # -1, -2, ..., -10. 
        if newvalue > topten[i]:
            if i < -1:
                topten[i+1] = topten[i]
            topten[i] = newvalue
        else:
            break

for v in data: add(v)
print topten
```

Comment: It works, but picking the initial value can be tricky. What if the number of calculations is suddenly lower than 10? What if a new calculation suddenly can have a lower value than this as a valid result? You could use `float('-inf')`, to make the latter less likely, but best would be to allow the list to grow at first. The algorithm works, though it isn't very efficient.

Comment: Thanks @ThijsvanDien, those are valid concerns. I like your heapq answer. But I also wanted to figure out how to fix mine. So, I came up with a solution. I've updated my answer with that. I do agree that worst-case complexity of my solution is something like N*10, as opposed to N*log2(10) using the heapq.